# How to be sure Babel is compiling both typescript and javascript files in a React Native project?

Tags: typescript, babeljs

**EDIT:**

**This [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/rnx-kit/docs/tools/metro-config#:%7E:text=The%20Babel%20plugin%20for%20TypeScript%20that%20comes%20with%20metro%2Dreact%2Dnative%2Dbabel%2Dpreset%20only%20strips%20the%20types.) for a package that helps with `metro` says:**

> “The Babel plugin for TypeScript that comes with metro-react-native-babel-preset only strips the types.”

**This tells me that typescript support is included in `metro-react-native-babel-preset` and, since I'm using it, I don't need `babel/preset-typescript` at all.**

**I guess for now I'm going to be content with my configuration as long as everything appears to work. Still, if anyone comes across this and can shed any light, I'd like to fully understand what's going on.**

ORIGINAL POST:

I've been working on an established(on the app stores) React Native project for about a year and am now starting the process of converting it to TypeScript. Since I'm already using Babel, I've decided to take the approach of only using TypeScript for type checking and letting Babel take care of compiling. I've discovered I need the `babel/preset-typescript` dependency to do this. Trying to configure it has opened up a lot of questions about how everything is actually working.

The `babel/preset-typescript` [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) says:

> You will need to specify --extensions ".ts" for @babel/cli & @babel/node cli's to handle .ts files.

I've never used the babel cli, actually never touched anything related to babel, I just assumed it was working automatically behind the scenes, as I know it ships with React Native. Seeing this makes me wonder, how do I make sure Babel is compiling my project(a mix of `ts` and `js` files) correctly if I'm not running this cli script to alert it to `ts` files?

I see there is an `allExtensions` [option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript#istsx:%7E:text=not%20be%20removed.-,allExtensions,-boolean%2C%20defaults%20to) that "Indicates that every file should be parsed as TS, TSX, or as TS without JSX ambiguities..." and an `isTSX` [option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript#istsx:%7E:text=Options-,isTSX,-boolean%2C%20defaults%20to) that "Forcibly enables jsx parsing." Those two together sort of sound like I might need them, but it's unclear, and then what about just plain `js` files? This [blog](https://lightrun.com/answers/babel-babel-preset-typescript-should-default-to-ts-and-tsx#:%7E:text=overrides%20the%20default%20and%20forces%20it%20to%20treat%20all%20files%20as%20TSX:%7E:text=That%20is%20the%20default%20behavior%20and%20it%20sounds%20like%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20actually%20want%20to%20set%20isTSX%20in%20the%20first%20place.) makes it sound like I *don't* want to enable `isTSX` so I'm all turned around.

To further complicate things, in React Native's *JavaScript Environment* [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/javascript-environment.html#:%7E:text=function%20foo(x%3A%20%7B%20hello%3A%20true%2C%20target%3A%20%27react%20native!%27%20%7D)%3A%20string%20%7B%7D%3B:%7E:text=function%20foo(x%3A%20%7B%20hello%3A%20true%2C%20target%3A%20%27react%20native!%27%20%7D)%3A%20string%20%7B%7D%3B) it says TypeScript is included in `metro-react-native-babel-preset`, which I am using, so now I'm wondering if I even need `babel/preset-typescript`. And then, if Babel ships with React Native, why do I even need to include `metro-react-native-babel-preset` in my `babelrc`, as I thought that was for custom configuration?

Here is my `babelrc` file for reference:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["."]
    }]
  ]
}
```

Appreciate any clarity anyone can bring!

Comment: Hey, a quick google search for "add typescript to react native app" got me this, should fix your problem: https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#adding-typescript-to-an-existing-project

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for your help! Yes, this is what I started with but as I went on things got more complicated. I don't think this is the full picture. I think this assumes you are going to use tsc to compile, which I'm not. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Here's a quote from the page: Out of the box, transforming your files to JavaScript works via the same Babel infrastructure as a non-TypeScript React Native project. We recommend that you use the TypeScript compiler only for type checking. If you have existing TypeScript code being ported to React Native, there are one or two caveats to using Babel instead of TypeScript.

Comment: @Jacob Ok, yes, I remember this too. So would you say I don't need the babel/preset-typescript dependency? It's still all so unclear to me. Thanks again!

Comment: You can always do `npm ls typescript` if you think you have it installed via a transitive dependency. Either way you say you are converting to TypeScript so your project now should list that as a `devDependency`. Similar reasoning for `@babel/preset-typescript`. If your project is going to use that to compile/transpile then it should likewise be a `devDependency`.

Comment: @morganney Thank you! Hmm, maybe I didn't make my question clear enough. I do have both installed under devDependencies, I was just not sure if/how I needed to tell Babel to check both `js` and `ts` files.

Comment: Depends on how your project is using babel. Sounds like bundled by metro while being transpiled by babel in the process. I've never used react native but sounds like you want to use `tsc` for type checking only. For that you can add a script to your package.json like `"check-types": "tsc --noEmit"`. You want to configure the metro preset to include `ts` files, that's what is using babel in your build process. Basically your question needs more details.

Comment: @morganney Yes, I believe you are right – bundled by metro while being transpiled by babel. And yes, I mentioned that I only want to use `tsc` for type checking, I'm good there. I will look into how to configure `metro-react-native-babel-preset` to include `ts` files. Thanks for your time.